# Spectral Representation: Calculation of upper cut-off numbers

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, stochastic-processes, spectral-analysis

Consider a two-dimensional stochastic field with power spectral density function $S_{ff}(k_1,k_2)$ given by:

$$S_{ff}(k_1,k_2)=σ^2\frac{b_1b_2}{4\pi}\exp{\left(-\left(\frac{b_1k_1}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{b_2k_2}{2}\right)^2\right)}$$

$$-k_{1u}\le k_1\le k_{1u},\ -k_{2u}\le k_2\le k_{2u}$$

where $k_{1u}$ and $k_{2u}$ are the upper cut-off numbers.

As stated in the literature, the following criterion is used to determine the values of $k_{1u}$ and $k_{2u}$:

$$\int_0^{k_{1u}}\int_{-k_{2u}}^{k_{2u}}S_{ff}(k_1,k_2)dk_1dk_2=(1-ε)\int_0^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}S_{ff}(k_1,k_2)dk_1dk_2$$

where $ε$ a very small number ($ε=0.001$).

In my case, with given parameters $b_1$ and $b_2$, I get the following equation:

$$\text{erf}\left(\frac{b_1k_{1u}}{2}\right)\text{erf}\left(\frac{b_2k_{2u}}{2}\right)=1-ε$$

So my question is how can I solve the last equation for $k_{1u}$ and $k_{2u}$? Assuming $\text{erf}\left(\frac{b_1k_{1u}}{2}\right)=\text{erf}\left(\frac{b_2k_{2u}}{2}\right)$ and solving the last equation this way seems pretty vague...

Thanks in advance